# Switch from mysql to mongodb ? or Use mysql with mongodb due to huge amount of data?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, yii2

Data of my yii2 project is stored in mysql but due to huge amount of data I want to find a solution, and my team suggest me to switch to mongodb or use mongodb with mysql. I can't convert to mongodb because my code includes join in many functions.
So, I want to use mysql as primary database with mongodb, But I am unable to use HasMany() relation between mysql model and mongodb model.
Please suggest me what can i do at this stage?

Comment: You should at leas tell what is "huge amount of data" in actual numbers to give some sort of scale to your problem.

Comment: @JamesZ more than 2gb.

Comment: 2GB is not huge..and size of itself is no great reason to switch , what is the problem you actually have?

Comment: @P.Salmon the data is increasing day by day, at this time we have data size approx 2gb but it will be more and i am facing with increasing load time. Can you please suggest how can i deal with this? We are switching to mongodb just because of data size.

Comment: Switching from mysql to mongodb is not a solution as same problem you'll face there as well. You need to do proper indexing on keys/columns your queries are using to reduce the loading time and performance. Learn to use `Explain` to analyse the queries and optimize them accordingly